# When I write that $\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x} = 0$, should I include the fact $x\neq0$?

Tags: logic

When I write that $\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x} = 0$, should I include the fact $x\neq0$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $1/x$ is not defined when $x=0$

Comment: No. $1/x-1/x=0/x$. $0/0$ is an indeterminate form.

Comment: @Tucker: That is irrelevant. $1/x$ is already undefined when $x=0$, so there is no need to consider $1/x-1/x$.

Comment: *"I haven't seen that remark when looking at similar expressions."* ... Where have you been looking? It's possible that the context of the discussion makes clear that $x$ is non-zero (perhaps as the side-length of a non-degenerate triangle). Of course, it's best to make these exclusions explicit, but sometimes writers can be informal and trust that their readers will fill in logical gaps. On sites like Math.SE or even Wikipedia, it's important to keep in mind that we aren't writing formal, peer-reviewed journal articles; oversights happen.

Comment: Unless there's some formal context that forces your hand one way or the other, you would generally write $x\neq 0$ if you want to draw attention to what happens if $x=0$ and omit it if you don't want to draw attention to that case (e.g. the bigger argument only needs minor adjustment for $x=0$).

Comment: [Wheel theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory) is worth mentioning here.

Comment: Please do not vandalise your post. If you feel the issue has been covered, consider accepting an answer (green tick).

Comment: If you would like to clarify your question, by all means do so. There are many questions which aren't of the best quality on this site, so please try to keep your question so that the answers can be saved on the site. You can see more on this [Meta Math SE post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28168/deleting-questions-with-answers).

Answer (score 3):

Yes you have to write $x\neq 0$. But why? Well division is really just multiplication. By definition, $x/y:=x\cdot \frac{1}{y}$ and multiplication is an operation defined on $\mathbb{R}$. To be precise, is is the map $\cdot: \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, $(x,y)\mapsto x\cdot y$. Therefore, in order to even talk about multiplying two elements, you need both to be in $\mathbb{R}$. But $\frac{1}{x}\not\in \mathbb{R}$ if $x=0$ (in fact it is not even defined).

Answer (score 1):

An equation is what is called a *statement form*; it includes a *placeholder*, here it's $x$.

Now we call any number a *solution* if the statement which is produced by substituting the placeholder by that number is a *statement* which is *true*.

Take $2x=6$, e.g.  By substituting $x$ by $5$ the statement $2\cdot5=6$ is achieved.  But as that statement isn't true, $5$ is no solution of that statement form.

Now there may be substitutions which don't produce a statement at all, but rather something incomputable (something that is not a number).  Incomputability arises in our case if you plug in $x=0$ as $1/0$ is not a number.

Hence $0$ is neither a solution nor not a solution of the given statement form.  In case you substitute any other number a statement which is true is produced.